# I am looking for a video annotation tool

Tags: image, annotations, tracking, vision

I am looking for a simple video annotation tool that contains the following future:

Create rectangles around objects in various frames and the tool allows to export these information (frame#, rect1.xy, etc...) into a txt file/excel file etc...

I have been searching the whole web today but could not find one solution. I only found vatic, but there you have to pay for Amazon's Mechanical Turk:

http://web.mit.edu/vondrick/vatic/

Anybody knows some tools that do the same thing?

Comment: What is this used for?

Comment: I am implementing a face tracker and to evaluate the performance/correctness of my tracker, I need to compare it to the correct information in every 10,50, or 100th frame: Compare where my tracker has localized the faces to the txt-file that says where the faces actually are.

Comment: how about using video editing techniques(how would a non-coder/video editor do it) ? would using mocha for after effects to track the face then export the keyframes to a .txt file which you can parse and compare with processing work ?

Comment: I finally found this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/via-tool/
You can draw rectangles, move them around and export the data to XML/txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still continue to use VATIC in offline mode without paying for Amazon's Mechanical Turk services.